# Remove Script tag from Encoded XSS String

Tags: javascript, xss

I get a string like this while trying to do a XSS..

```
xss%22%3E%3Cscript%3Econfirm%28document.cookie%29%3C%2fscript%3Exs
```

What would be the best possible way to prevent this in javascript ?

**Edit**

I want the data like `xsscExs`

Comment: Maybe use Google's sanitizer which is heavily tested and used to prevent a lot of tainted input problems? https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer

Comment: When you're doing the XSS, what exactly do you want to prevent? When you're receiving the XSS attack, show us your code! And again, what part of this do you want to prevent, and why would use javascript for that?

Comment: Sorry @Bergi .. Client code dude. and javascript because the data is from a diff source and we dont have access to backend code.. So the real question is can we do it in javascript

Comment: No, if there is an XSS hole then you cannot close it by clientside javascript. If there is no hole, please describe your problem. What do you want to prevent?